# Exporting sql data to excel using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to export data from my MySQL database to an excel file. Here is my code -

```
function cleanData(&$str) {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    //File to export
    $filename = "export_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed!');
    while(false != ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
        if(!$flag) {
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    exit;
    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

The data comes fine but the header is one row right shifted. The rest of the data starts from the 1st column. How can i fix it?

Comment: Why is nobody ever aware of PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: And note that a tab-separated value file isn't an Excel file, it's a file that Excel can read.... there is a difference

Comment: Thanks, solved using fputcsv()